# Is it appropriate to work on papers outside of my doctorate?

Tags: computer-science, united-kingdom

I am starting my PhD in October at a UK University. I am skipping my masters and going straight to doing my PhD. Although this has saved me time, it has also removed my opportunity to publish my masters and I will therefore be starting with one less publication than usual. I should also mention I have been given a scholarship to do my doctorate at the university.

Now the issue is that my undergrad supervisor, who works at a different university to the one I'm doing my doctorate, has expressed interest in continuing to work with me on the project I was doing under his supervision. However I think he is hesitant as I have accepted the place at a different university. Like I said I am skipping my masters and therefore could use as many publishing opportunities as possible.

My question is whether it is appropriate to ask for permission to continue working with my undergrad supervisor. I would still be working on work directly related to my PhD, however will also be working on the other project in my free time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you need to consult with your doctoral advisor on this in case they think it might interfere with your progress. However, that is a matter of time and effort that might be spent better. It shouldn't be a question of publishing, per se, though.

But you have time in the short term to work on anything you like.

If you already have a doctoral advisor, though, it would be a good idea to discuss it with them.